# Why is this Kubernetes Ingress not accepting traffic?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to set up a simple HTTP web server on Kubernetes and expose it with the Ephemeral external IP. However when launch it and try and visit one of the URLs at `x.x.x.x/something` I get:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

My config is simply:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/my-repo-name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-balancer-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 32111
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-app
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: web-balancer-service
    servicePort: 8080
```

If I describe the *ingress* I see that the backend is "Unknown". Is there a problem with my spec?

```
Name:             my-ingress-app
Namespace:        default
Address:          x.x.x.x
Default backend:  web-balancer-service:8080 (10.60.0.57:32111)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     web-balancer-service:8080 (10.60.0.57:32111)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:         {"k8s-be-30330--f4bbd8cbe40f4567":"Unknown"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:  k8s-fw-default-my-ingress-app--f4bbd8cbe40f4567
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:     k8s-tp-default-my-ingress-app--f4bbd8cbe40f4567
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:          k8s-um-default-my-ingress-app--f4bbd8cbe40f4567
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     7m18s  loadbalancer-controller  default/my-ingress-app
  Normal  CREATE  6m12s  loadbalancer-controller  ip: x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting is the error from Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), so I am assuming you are running in in GKE on Google Cloud.

First, make sure that containers (pods of the deployment) are actually listening to the port `32111`. You have this as the `targetPort` on the service, which means the service will receive traffic on port `8080`, but send them to the port `32111` of the pods that it matches. Looks like:

```
--(traffic)---> :8080 (service) ---> :32111 (pods)
```

I suspect this, because in your pod spec you have `containerPort: 8080`, which is an indicator that the pod actually listens to `8080` as well, not `32111`.

Therefore, first, try to change the `targetPort` of the Service to `8080` as well.

After giving it some time, if it doesn't start working, check if you have actually HTTP Load Balancing enabled in your cluster. It looks like this, when you are creating the cluster on the Google Cloud Console:
[image: screenshot]

On the existing cluster, go to its details on GCP console, and check the addons section:

[image: addons]

Comment: Thank you the issue was indeed the targetPort - also waiting about 10 minutes for it to before healthy.